# html node loses mouse move event when mouse is moved to fast

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousemove

I bound a "mouse move" handler to a html node to move it around the screen. So far so good. But when I move the mouse to fast the mouse pointer loses the connection to the node and did not get further move events.

I know I could register "mouse move" for the entire document, but is this the only possible solution. Is it possible to stick the mouse to the node.

Or should I use "mouse out" or "mouse leave" to detect and catch it again?

Comment: [setCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) only for Mozilla

Comment: catching not possible, because I can not change the position of the mouse ;-(

Comment: Should I compute the mouse speed and adjust the coordinates with this result so it can`t lose "mouse move"?

Answer (score -1):

So after some more experiments, I think the best option is to start with a "mouse down" to detect the node and handling the "mouse move" with an outer node.